# Is it possible to add resourcekey to a asp:DynamicControl?

Tags: asp.net, meta

I can't figure out how to add a meta:resourcekey tag to an asp:DynamicControl control.  Can someone help me?  Here's a working example for a basic label:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Owner" meta:resourcekey="Label1Resource1"></asp:Label>
```

But what about this (it's going to generate the label and the textbox attached to the property:

```
  <asp:DynamicControl Mode="Edit" DataField="Target" meta:resourcekey="Target" runat="server" />
```

The label will never be translated to another language according the the resourcekey "Target".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are in the same situation as me, I have managed to find a way to work around my problem using resource files.  You need to create localized resource files and use them in your object classes as attributes like this:

```
 [Display(ResourceType = typeof(namespaceofyourressource), Name = "resourcekey")]
 [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(namespaceofyourressource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "resourcekey")]
 [StringLength(150)]
 public string NameEn { get; set; }
```

The dynamics controls will be generated correctly.

Comment: Please upvote if this is helpful for you.  Thank you.